# What does mailbox quota mean?

Tags: web-hosting, mail

I want to publish my website and I don't know which host to choose. A free host which has "Mailbox quota: maximum-500", and a paid host which has "Mailbox quota: unlimited". What does mailbox quota mean and how much represents 500? Mb of emails or I can send maximum 500 emails?

Comment: A mailbox quota will normally be measured in MB, but you should ask your host for clarification. There can be limits on the number of emails that can be sent in a given time period.

Comment: It depends upon what you intend to do? If you want to send and receive e-mail, then a lot can depend upon if your e-mail client and whether it can effectively download and delete the e-mail (server side). If you are using an e-mail client and check your e-mail moderately often and do not receive a lot of e-mail (or spam) then you should be okay with the free option. However, I warn you, you do get what you pay for. Free hosts or even very cheap hosts come at a cost- you cannot escape that simple fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the mail servers have a storage limit that you cannot exceed.

If your mailbox has a quota set to 500MB, once the limit in size is reached, you will not be able to receive emails since the mailbox would be deemed full.

However, if you get unlimited, you will never actually fill up your mailbox.

Keep in mind, as long as you are regularly cleaning out your email account, having a quota would not be an issue, since you're deleting the emails.

Attachments do count towards the quota as well, so if you receive a lot of large files such as images, it may be wise to have unlimited.

Just using ballpark figures from my current email server, without attachments you should be able to store over 10k emails on 500MB of space.